# Apache flink: Issues after configuring HA (using zookeeper setting)

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Good Day. I am using Flink (1.18) version and zookeeper (3.7.2) for our flink cluster. Job manager has been deployed on "Application mode" and when HA is disabled (high-availability.type: NONE) we are able to start multiple jobs for a single application. But when I setup the Zookeeper as the HA type (high-availability.type: zookeeper), we are only seeing only one job is getting executed on the Flink dashboard. Following are the parameters setup for the Zookeeper based HA setup on the flink-conf.yaml. Please let us know if anyone has experienced similar issues and have any suggestions. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Note: We are using a Streaming application.

1. high-availability.storageDir: /opt/flink/data
2. high-availability.cluster-id: test
3. high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: localhost:2181
4. high-availability.type: NONE

We need to get the Flink HA up and running for fault tolerance/recovery.

Comment: Also we use high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /dp/configs/flinkha

Comment: We are unable to see multiple jobs getting executed on the flink cluster when HA is enabled for Application mode of deployment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The issue can be reproduced by enabling high-availability.type: zookeeper and in the flink client code try to call env.executeAsync() for multiple instance of job for the same application. Now open Dashboard and check the number of jobs (same can be tried via REST api call too).